# How to convert the null values to empty string in php array?

Tags: php, arrays, null

I want to convert this array that Array[4] should not give null it can give blank space (empty string).

```
Array (
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 0
    [3] => V
    [4] => 
    [5] => N 
);
```

(The reason for the change, unrelated to the general question)

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception
'PDOException' with message 'Database
error [23000]: Column 'message' cannot
be null, driver error code is 1048' in
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Then you should just loop through array elements, check each value for null and replace it with empty string. Something like that:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_null($value)) {
         $array[$key] = "";
    }
}
```

Also, you can implement checking function and use [array_map()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function.

Answer (score 46):

PHP 5.3+

```
$array = array_map(function($v){
    return (is_null($v)) ? "" : $v;
},$array);
```

Answer (score 9):

There is even better/shorter/simpler solution. Compilation of already given answers. For initial data

> ```
> [1, 4, "0", "V", null, false, true, 'true', "N"]
> ```

with

```
$result = array_map('strval', $arr);
```

*$result* will be

> ```
> ['1', '4', '0', 'V', '', '', '1', 'true', 'N']
> ```

This should work even in php4 :)

Answer (score 8):

This will map the array to a new array that utilizes the null ternary operator to either include an original value of the array, or an empty string if that value is null.

```
$array = array_map(function($v){
    return $v ?: '';
},$array);
```

Comment: PHP7.4: `$array = array_map(fn($v) => $v ?: '', $array);` :D

Comment: Technically `?:` would replace falsey values with empty string. `??` could be used to only replace null values - this is only available PHP7+

Answer (score 2):

You can use this instead.

```
array_map(function($val){return is_null($val)? "" : $val;},$result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a technique I haven't seen mentioned in the above answers:

```
$val = strval(@$arr["notfound"]);  // will not generate errors and
                                   // defaults to an empty string
```

This is super handy for `$_GET` parameter loading to keep things short and readable. Bonus, you can replace `strval()` with `trim()` ... or with `intval()` if you only accept integers.

The default for `intval` will be `0` if missing or a non-numeric value. The default for `strval` is `""` if empty, null or false.

```
$val_str = strval(@$_GET['q']);
$val_int = intval(@$_GET['offset']);
```

[**See DEMO**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b8980978d4018a8c893b825c4dc5c65ec011117c)

Now for an array, you'll still need to loop over every value and set it. But it's very readable, IMO:

```
$arr = Array (1, 4, "0", "V", null, false, true, 'true', "N");

foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
  $arr[$key] = strval($value);
}

echo ("['".implode("','", $arr)."']");
```

Here is the result:

> ```
> ['1','4','0','V','','','1','true','N']
> ```

Interesting is that `true` becomes "1", but `'true'` stays a string and that `false` becomes and empty string `""`.

Now the same data using `$arr[$key] = intval($value);` produces this result:

> ```
> ['1','4','0','0','0','0','1','0','0']
> ```

Comment: `$val_int = intval(@$_GET['offset']);` its Work for me thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
if($value===NULL)
{
$array[$key]="";
}
}
```

Comment: `0 == NULL` is `TRUE` also. Should have used identity (`===`).

Answer (score 1):

Use this function. This will replace null to empty string in nested array also

```
$arr = array(
          "key1"=>"value1",
          "key2"=>null,
          "key3"=>array(
                 "subkey1"=>null, 
                 "subkey2"=>"subvalue2"),
          "key4"=>null);

    echo json_encode(replace_null_with_empty_string($arr));

   function replace_null_with_empty_string($array)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
        {
            if(is_array($value))
                $array[$key] = replace_null_with_empty_string($value);
            else
            {
                if (is_null($value))
                    $array[$key] = "";
            }
        }
        return $array;
    }
```

Output will be :

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "",
  "key3": {
    "subkey1": "",
    "subkey2": "subvalue2"
  },
  "key4": ""
}
```

Try online here : https://3v4l.org/7uXTL

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in one line using:

```
array_walk($array_json_return,function(&$item){$item=strval($item);});
```

here $array_json_return is the array.