# How to convert '' to null in a php array?

Tags: php, arrays

How to convert empty strings to null within an array? I needed this to clean up prior to json exporting and inserting to my db.

e.g.

```
$array[0]['name'] = 'my name';
$array[1]['name'] = '';
$array[2]['name'] = null;
$array[3]['name'] = 'my name 2';
```

to

```
$array[0]['name'] = 'my name';
$array[1]['name'] = null;
$array[2]['name'] = null;
$array[3]['name'] = 'my name 2';
```

I found a useful snippet in another question that I modified. I put it here for anyone else looking, and maybe better/faster options may exist.

Comment: note that null and `''` are NOT the same thing. null is "unknown" or "uninitialized". `''` is "string that happens to be empty"... unless you're dealing with oracle...

Comment: Your question's code shows that you are replacing array keys that are empty strings with null. You *can* do that, but a null key is identical in function to an empty string key. Both will be encoded in JSON as "". So, converting '' to null won't make a difference.

Comment: @MarcB Yes, that's why I need to convert from '' to null. I want null in my database, not ''.

Comment: @kainaw: no, json_encode will turn php null into a javascript null: `$x = array('', null); echo json_encode($x);` produces `["",null]`

Comment: `array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$value) { $value = ($value === '') ? null : $value; } );`

Comment: @MarcB You are correct for VALUES. The original question had the `''` and `null` as KEYS. JSON will encode both `''` and `null` key values as "". Easy to check - try it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For PHP 5.3+, this runs through all variables in an array which are an empty string '', and coverts them to null.

```
function clean_array($array) {
  return array_map(function($v){
    return ($v === '') ? NULL : $v;
  }, $array);
}
```

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16187390/2868238).

Comment: If you are replacing VALUES of `''` with `null` and not KEYS as the question shows, it would faster to str_replace the JSON: `$json = str_replace('""','null',$json);`

Comment: @kainaw My main reason for doing this is inserting null to the db, instead of ''. I agree, it would be faster to manipulate the json directly if I was doing just that.